# Cannot run composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I just install composer. On windows 8, it works perfectly. Then I tried to install in mac with OS mountain lion, and PHP 5.5.3. To install I run this:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check
```

It installed successfully, but with warning: segmentation fault.
So now I am still in the same folder where composer.phar is located. I try typing:

```
php composer.phar
```

I got this return:

```
671 segmentation fault  php composer.phar
```

When I type:

```
composer --version
```

not a recognized command. Is there a bug with the latest version of composer running in Mac OS using latest PHP ?

Comment: what happens if you run `./composer.phar`?

Comment: Can you download `composer.phar` from manually from http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar and tell us if it's CRC / MD5 checksum is the same as for the file that was created by installer?

Comment: It returns [1]    423 segmentation fault  ./composer.phar. I've tried manual download. Also output segmentation fault. I found this: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/226, it says the bug appears for PHP 5.3.2 and it should be fixed by now. But I am using PHP 5.5.3 in Mac. In windows, I am using PHP 5.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a segmentation fault problem as well and I tried to run:

```
strace ./composer.phar command
```

In my case, it was simply a badly configured TEMPDIR (it didn't exist)

Hope it helps!